# Can anyone suggest me a solver for this system of PDEs?

Tags: solver, pde

I'm currently in trouble with solving a system of 1-dimentional, 1st order PDEs [See the PDEs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X37bA.png). I've tried MATALAB PDEPE, and FiPy, but both of them doesn't work for this problem. The challenge is the very complicated f functions (see the picture), which prevent me to rearrage the equations into the standard form.

So can anyone suggest me a solver? Better on MATLAB or Python platform, but others are also acceptable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would do better asking on one of the SE Math sites ...

Comment: Could you please give me a specific site?

Comment: You can find the sites in "Stack Exchange Network" menu in the page footer.  Scroll down ...